# How and when did Karna came to know that he was a kshatriya?

Tags: mahabharata, karna, parashurama

I have read in many questions related to this  on stackexchange (like [Mahabharat Parshuram's curse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29818/16631)) that Karna knew that he was a Kshatriya. But who told Karna about his original caste and when?