# In Hinduism, which of our actions make god angry against us?

Tags: gods, sin

Which actions of ours are offensive towards gods? (Drinking, Dating, Masturbation, eating non veg etc). Can anyone provide me a list with some explanation? Are these sins?

Comment: Karma is stored in Manomaya kosha.. ie. In sheath of mind... Hence Bhava/intention of a Karma in mind makes a Karma good or bad... same Karma gives different results in different intentions... for eg. If a man kills another in anger and selfishness then he accumulates bad Karma of that actuvity... if YamRaj kills a person (when his time is over) he is just doing his duty and he isn't attached with that duty... so even if relatives and others may curse him God saves him.... similarly act of killing with intention to save others body also generate good karma.... same act killing results differ..

Comment: Upanishads in single sentence declare dharma as 'Atmanam Pratikulani Pareshaam na Samacharet' ie. Don't do that thing to other if that thing someone does on you it is Pratikula/don't liked by you... Hence Intentions/Bhava beside a Karma is important...  Hence if others aren't affected Pratikula/Oppositely by your behaviour it isn't sin... In eating non. Veg there is standard philosophy in Buddhism... Lord Buddha says " One shouldn't eat meat if that is known heard or suspected that the animal was alive and it was killed for him. One can eat meat if one knows that it wasn't killed for him..."

Comment: God doesn't become angry by an activity of ours... it is because we solely are responsible for the reward and Punishment of karmas done by us...God may appear to be angry in certain acts of us... it is not due to Nature of God... It is due to compassion of God toward us... it is like a guide by God to us.... God wants that we may be freed from cycles of birth and rebirth due to his compassion seeing our dukkha....so he may act angry as a part of his leela to guide us....

Comment: In Christianity, God gets angry upon you for doing or not doing something. Not in Hinduism. ;)

Comment: @Tezz what about masturbation?

Comment: It also depends on your intention... for eg. There are Vamacharas who think liberation is possible from masturbation and sex... there are advanced yogic positions and mudras from which semen can be retained and also reabsorbed through yoga... but anyhow it causes decreases in your Tejas energy... also you may become servant of 'Kama' which is one of our Panchashatru...so Indriya control is recommended...

Comment: Masturbation , Eating non-veg and dating are all sins for a jiva in bramhachari(studentship) phase of life,see manusmriti for more details http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu.htm. Since you are a bramhin it is a sin to eat non-veg and it holds for your entire lifetime. While masturbation and dating(romance) is allowed after you are married, but no gandharava vivah(Casual sex with another women) is allowed. It is recommended that you should establish physical relationship with your wife only. Drinking is not a sin but if want to be a mentally/physically healthy person then avoid it.

Comment: @Yogi But I have eaten non veg since I was very small. I quit drinking and dating. But I started masturbation from the time when I didn't realize it is bad so now i really have problems quitting these.

Comment: God is not angry with anyone. In fact God loves you unconditionally! If your son cries to you that 'I'm not able to leave my addiction to cigarettes', then wont you do everything in your power to help him? How much more God who is all powerful and loving. If you focus on God, all other things fade away on their own. Everything is under the control of God, including your addictions. Pray to Him, why won't He liberate you! All the best.

Comment: @Sai Helpful and optimistic

Comment: @AnishSharma God will not get angry for your actions. What we sow is what we reap. God doesn't involve in our daily activities. Our thoughts and actions will decide our destiny. Drinking doesn't make God angry but you acquire " TAMO GUNA" (laziness, loss of intelligence and memory, ) and you health will be deteriorated if you drink more. Similarly in [Masturbation](http://selfdefinition.org/celibacy/quotes/dhananjay-harm-of-masturbation.htm), semen is wasted and there by OJAS, the subtle fluid.

Comment: @AnishSharma  In [Premarital sex](http://selfdefinition.org/celibacy/quotes/dhananjay-astral-connection.htm), people are actually messing up here by forming Sukshama Nadis through Mooladhara Chakra with various people which affect them later.  One can [eat Non Veg](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8218/3500) if it is necessary for his/her survival. No scripture says to follow strict Vegetarinism, All those who say to follow strict Vegetarianism are half baked guys. I'm reiterating once again, SIN IS ABRAHAMIC CONCEPT. Everything has reason in Hinduism.

Comment: There's a verse in bhagavatam where Narayana says his wrath is triggered when dharma, vedas, bramhanas, cows, his devotees and very lastly himself are disparaged. Let me see if I can find the verse.

Answer (score 3):

God is a non-doer and is unattached to the Universe and its living beings.
It's primordial nature, the shakti of Brahman, which brings forth the creation. Brahman does not interfere in the creation.

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
>   again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
>   owing to Nature's sway over them.

Gita 9.8

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, **because I remain detached
>   like one unconcerned in their midst.**

Gita 9.9

The net result of God's non-attachment is that any paapa we do, only damages us by accumulation of bad karma and destruction of our spiritual nature. God is not angry. Ishvara only distributes the fruits of our karma.

**Is there a list of our sins?**

> **Lust, anger and greed** - this triad leads to the destruction of man's
>   spiritual nature. They form the gateway to hell; they should be
>   abandoned.

Gita 16.21

**Vidura on Gates of hell**

> Great fear springeth from these three crimes, viz, theft of other’s
>   property, outrage on other’s wives, and breach with friends. These
>   three, besides, being destructive of one’s self, are the gates of
>   hell, viz, **lust, anger, and covetousness**. Therefore, everyone should
>   renounce them.

[Mahabharata, UdyogaParva, Section 33]