# Is the concept of divine retribution(punishment) mentioned in the Vedas and upanishades?

Tags: vedas, gods, upanishads, brahman

[Divine retribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_retribution) : Divine retribution is supernatural punishment of a person, a group of people, or everyone by a deity in response to some action. Many cultures have a story about how a deity exacted punishment upon previous inhabitants of their land, causing their doom.

So God personally punishes people or individuals because of there sins/bad karma.

Is this concept mentioned in the Upanishad and the Vedas,  do advaita vedanta believes in these kinds of doctrines?

Comment: This question is answered here:https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12196/in-hinduism-which-of-our-actions-make-god-angry-against-us/21671#21671

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay I didn't asked from gita and Mahabharata but from Upanishads and the Vedas. And I also asked the view of adi shankaracharya

Comment: Please see #3 and #4 in this link to Rig veda. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07046.htm It is requesting Rudra not to cause harm. Would this be what you are looking for?