# What is the exact dharma to be followed in case of a marriage outside the caste or religion?

Tags: dharma, marriage, caste-system, dharma-shastras, brahmins

What exactly does the dharma say in the tricky circumstances or situation where a brahmin community girl loves and willing to marry a non-brahmin hindu/non-religion boy.

What Dharma is to be followed by her parents (especially girl's father), her siblings or others based on the Bhagavad Gita/Vedas/Shastra/other scriptures/puranas etc...?

Comment: Guna is important. People with SatvaGuna are Brahmins. See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8218/3500). Convince them **Varna is important not Kula or caste** with proper explanation. Tell them not all people are exhibiting their innate nature in this Kali Yuga.. People just get deluded  and follow fad forgetting true inherent nature.

Comment: There is always the example of Devayani the daughter of Shukracharya marrying the Kshatriya King Yayati even though the rules didn't allow their marriage.

Comment: I didnt get your point on 'Varna is important not caste' what does it mean? Still your answer is not understanding me very clear as per dharma or shastras point of view in that kind of situation.

Comment: Devayani example is only one sided love but not both sides. Also Shukracharya is Brahman but being guru for demons is agreed for his daughter wish to marry kshatriya person due to the situation that the kshatriya guy was saved Devayani. 
But as per shastras and as per current Kaliyuga in current generation world, what a parent of a daughter has to act or dharma has to follow and any objection or rules framed in any scriptures or vedas for Brahman marriages in this Kaliyuga ?

Comment: In Ancient India, Varna was important factor and profession was based on Varna and Varna in turn depends on innate Guna.Varna in Sanskrit means color and it  describes Guna of a human. So, everything was logical. But during British rule, Varna was replaced with Caste (Kula). Caste is formed by living in groups and this has nothing to do with Hinduism. Varna and Caste are two different things. First, know difference between Varna and Caste. Supreme Purusha made classification in society based on Varna

Comment: a brahmin girl marrying a non-brahmin boy is a pratiloma vivaha (forbidden by shastras). other way around is anuloma (accepted), but not as first marriage i.e. brahmin boy can marry non-brahmin girl as a 2nd (or higher no.) wife. it seems like you are the father caught in this dilemma ? lovingly tell your daughter that it is against the wishes of bhagavan and shastras and elders. if she is adamant, then she is putting all their happiness beneath her own, and she has to be prepared to face the consequences whether they be good or bad (life is always a mix of both).

Comment: @Surya , yayati initially refused because it was against dharma. shukracharya used his tapo-balam to ensure that the pratiloma-vivaha would not count as a sin against yayati, basically like bribing chitra-gupta to change records :).. if you are shukracharya, and your daughter is devayani, and the boy is yayati, then maybe it can be done.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, 'Guna is important'. Does it mean 'Guna ALONE is important'. One can be born in a brahmin family and not be satvik. One can be satvik and not be born in a brahmin family. BOTH satvik guna and brahmin birth are required to be a brahmin/dvija (wear upaveeta, recite vedas, etc.). these socio-reformist comments like 'guna is important, not kula/caste' don't help the actual issue. those who are mainly satvik in previous janma get birth as brahmin now, so that logic holds true even for birth-based varna. you still have to cultivate guna though. birth is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: @ram Not Reformist comments but attested by Sastras like Mahabharata Anushasana Parva and Shiva Purana. Varna Dharma was flexible but some Dharshana philosophers made it rigid with their interpretations. We can discuss in chat if we want to. But there are no explicit statements in scriptures which say Varna can't be changed in this birth.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, nobody is denying that birth-varna cannot be changed. But it is extremely , extremely rare. And that too, not just because of the individual's efforts, but also due to major tapo-balam from parents (e.g. Richika - Vishvamitra). these are exceptions, not the rule. Saying it is flexible gives easy way out for people and cause varna-sankara. Krishna says 'sreyan svardharmo, paradharmo bhayavaha'. Will you go around saying 'high-school drop outs can become like Sachin Tendulkar in cricket' ? Just because one or two guys did it, it is highly misleading to say 'anyone can do it'

Comment: Oh no! Mar was again acting like it is rare when Vedic, Tantrik & other authors have all done it !! Yudhishthir said that intercaste marriage is the norm and you cannot determine anybody's caste because of that.... even in those days it was the norm!! Hindu gods like Shiv, Vishnu, and puranic scriptures have also said Varna change is FOR EVERYONE !! Mar follows Adi Shankar of SMRITI sect !!