# Why do many Hindus eat meat and fish? Eating meat and fish directly violates the principle of Ahimsa

Tags: food, non-vegetarian, ahimsa, meat

Ahimsa is one of the Yamas of the Vedic religion. My question is why do so many Hindus eat meat and fish?
Eating meat and fish directly violates the principle of Ahimsa.

Comment: Check this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33578/647 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Hindus vegetarian? What is the real meaning of the word 'mamsah' (मांसः) or meat?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/why-are-hindus-vegetarian-what-is-the-real-meaning-of-the-word-mamsah-%e0%a4%ae%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%82%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%83)

Comment: https://rockmine.blogspot.com/2023/10/stackexchange-why-do-many-hindus-eat.html I hope this addresses your question