# Vegetarianism amongst Bengali Vaishnavas

Tags: vaishnavism, non-vegetarian

Historically, what diet did Bengali Vaishnavas have? I've heard that the majority ate fish, with some sources saying that Bengalis considered fish veg.

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/625/why-bengali-brahmins-are-non-vegetarians